# How to ask people to sit closer together in order to make a room for somebody else

Tags: phrase-usage

Imagine you are going to sit on a bench where two persons have sit in the way that you would be short of room. How shall you ask them to sit closer in the manner that you could sit too? Does my self-made sentence bellow sound natural to you? If not please let me know what a native speaker would say in such a moment:

> - Could you please **sit** **a little** closer together?

**Added:** I doubt if using "a little" in the way I used is natural.

Comment: Your use of "a little" is natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know them, approach the end you wish to sit on and ask—

> Would you mind please?
>
> Would you mind if I sit / join you?

The action of making room would be inferred by the request.

If you know them in a friendly way, you can ask—

> Scooch over.

Comment: or "scoot over"